# Facebook permission to comment a friends post

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-php-sdk

I'm looking for the facebook permission(s) to comment and like a friends post who isn't using the application. With the `publish_actions` permission it is possible to comment the own post through `post_id` but when I'm trying the same code to comment a friends post it's giving me the `(#200) Permissions error`.

Is that even possible?

Here is the code:

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
         $session,
         'POST',
         '/'.$fb_post_id.'/comments',
         array (
                 'message' => 'this is a test comment'
         )
))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

And these are the permissions I'm using:
`publish_actions, manage_pages, publish_pages, user_location, user_hometown`

EDIT: Posting a comment to the own facebook post is working fine. But posting a comment to a friends post isn't work.

Comment: @luschn I hope that's enough code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it does work on your own posts, and not on the posts of friends, it most likely just does not work at all. You can´t post to the wall of friends either, so it would make sense. It would be way too easy to create a spammy App if that would be possible.

Afaik it is not possible to like the post of a friend either.

Comment: Is that a suggestion or do you know that it isn't possible. Because I think facebook would give me another error and not a permission error if it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: it´s basically an educated guess, but i am 99% sure ;)

Comment: about liking: you can´t do that with the api. btw, what would the exact use case for this be?